# CSS3 transition-timing-function

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I need to animate my div top like on slots in [this link](https://www.netent.com/games/slots/reel-steal/). 
I have made some [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xy1c0822/), but my animation doesn't work properly. I'm trying to do this with `jquery.easing.js`, same result. Can someone explain me what's wrong and how can I fix that.

My CSS:

```
.box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    top: 40px;    
    background: red;
    -webkit-transition-duration: .2s;
      transition-duration: 2s;
      -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.75, 1.95, .66,.56);
      transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.75, 1.95, .66, .56);
      -webkit-transition-property: top;
}
.box:hover{
    top: 500px;
}
```

Comment: Your jsFiddle link is wrong. Try correcting that?

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to achieve (the site you have linked does not have any elements animated as far as I can see). Are you trying to have the box animate all the way down when it's hovered on?

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is not that the timing function doesn't work properly, but that when the div moves, it looses the focus and the hover...

Is this what you want ?

```css
.launcher {
    width: 200px;
   height: 100px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
  left: 0px;
    background: red;
    -webkit-transition-duration: .2s;
      transition-duration: 2s;
      -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.75, 1.95, .66,.56);
      transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.75, 1.95, .66, .56);
      -webkit-transition-property: left;
}
.launcher:hover + .box{
    left: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="launcher">hover me</div>
<div class="box"></div>
```